# What does the ♥ operation do here? 2 ♥ 5 = 13, so 5 ♥ 24 =?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle

I am trying to answer this puzzle - which of the five potential answers is correct, and why?

> I. 2 ♥ 5 = 13
> II. 4 ♥ 10 = 74
> III. 3 ♥ 2 = 29
> IV. 5 ♥ 24 = ?
>
> - A) 146
> - B) 147
> - C) 148
> - D) 149
> - E) 150

This test comes from the Metropol iq1 book

Comment: The link you've given doesn't seem to go to anything containing this puzzle. Please provide attribution that actually enables readers to know where the puzzle comes from. Thanks!

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan why is proper attribution a requirement, here? are puzzlers stingy on IP?

Comment: We want to discourage plagiarism. Both because Plagiarism Is Bad and because we've found that in the absence of such rules we get deluged with not-very-interesting puzzles that people want solved in order to do their schoolwork, cheat on tests, win online competitions, etc. These usually aren't much fun to solve, they're often copyright infringements, solving them here is unfair to other solvers, and usually the person asking for help here would actually have more fun and learn more by solving the puzzle themselves.

Comment: So, we require people posting puzzles to tell us where they come from, which hopefully results in giving due credit to the people who did the hard work of creating the puzzles; and if where they come from turns out to be somewhere inappropriate (e.g., OP is trying to cheat in a competition), then we can take appropriate action. Of course sometimes posters will just plain lie about where a puzzle comes from, but it's usually not so difficult to tell when they're doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is below

> $5^3+24 = 149$